# jQuery: Change an element value after Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to change the value of a span after using jQuery.ajax.

### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.kssico', function(event) {
    var for_uid = $(this).parents("li").attr('data'),
        for_name = $(this).parents("li").attr('unme'),
        dataString = "for_uid=" + for_uid + "&for_name=" + for_name; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (html) {
            if(html=="300") {
                $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $(this).parents("li span.mi-val").html(html);
                $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("The Requested Action Has Been Notified To Your Friend.");
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<li class="mispan main-span" >
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h3 class="miheader">Dewashree Singh</h3>
        <a >
            <div class="miprofile-pic-cnt" ></div>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn kssico miclickks">
                    <img src="/lisps.png"><span class="mi-val">0</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn bdico miclickbd">
                    <img src="/besd.png"><span class="mi-val">1</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I click on `a.miclickks` it should complete the Ajax call and return a value too be placed inside the span on the button anchor. However, nothing is being changed!

### jsFiddle

Comment: What span you need to be changed ?

Comment: Please post the rest of the relevant jQuery, especially the AJAX part. Also, have you tried debugging with the devloper tools to see what's going on? Errors and AJAX data coming across?

Comment: i want span html changed to the ajax call return value of this `            <a href="#" class="btn kssico miclickks">
                <img src="/lisps.png"><span class="mi-val">0</span>
            </a>`

Comment: `mi-val` is a child of `micclickks`, not a parent.

Comment: `$(this).find("span.mi-val").html(html);`..

Comment: @MohammadAdil this didnt worked

Comment: `this` in the context of success handler refers to window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your whole code looks like, but you should be able to modify this to do what you are trying to:

```
$('#id').on('click', function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'wherever.php',
        success: function(html) {
          $(that).find("li span.mi-val").html(html);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems. The first is that as @Barmar posted above, mi-val is a child of micclickks, not a parent. The second is that your ajax complete function is asynchronous, so $(this) isn't what you expect it will be. Both of these are solvable though.

Your code is a bit messy and your html is missing the proper attributes, but this is I think roughly what you want:

```
$('.kssico').on('click', function(event) {

     var for_uid = $(this).parents("li").attr('data'); //the li element in your html doesn't have a data attribute
     var for_name = $(this).parents("li").attr('unme'); //the li element in your html doesn't have a 'unme' attribute
     var dataString = "for_uid=" + for_uid + "&for_name=" + for_name; 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context: this,
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (html) {
        if(html=="300")
        {
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
         }
        else
        {
            $(this).parents("li span.mi-val").html(html);
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("The Requested Action Has Been Notified To Your Friend.");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: It probably didn't work because of the reasons I mentioned in your post - your html elements don't have the correct attributes. Put up a jsfiddle so that we can at least all see what it is you're working with.